# Plotting the UK election results using Python, Pandas and Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, geopandas

as an exercise I am trying to plot out the UK's general election results from 2017. I have used Pandas to manipulate my dataframe and geopandas to visualise the results where every region is coloured by the winning party, conservative: blue, labour: red etc...

I have managed to plot it out but no matter what I do - the colours are not coming out correctly! Below I have attached my code, my output and what the output should look like, and any help would be much appreciated.

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import multipolygon, polygon, Polygon, MultiPolygon
%matplotlib inline

uk_map = gpd.read_file('Westminster_Parliamentary_Constituencies__December_2017__UK_BGC_V2.shp')
#shape file of the uk

df = pd.read_csv('uk_election_data_v2.csv')
#election results

uk_map.rename(columns={'PCON17NM':'Constituency'}, inplace=True)
uk_map.sort_values('Constituency', inplace=True)

df.sort_values('Constituency', inplace=True)

party_colours={'Conservative':'#0087dc',
               'Liberal Democrat':'#FDBB30',
               'Labour':'#d50000',
               'SNP':'#FFF95D',
               'Green':'#00FF00',
               'Independent':'#800080',
               'Sinn Fein':'#228B22',
               'Democratic Unionist':'#808080',
               'Plaid Cymru':'#FF5733'
              }
#dictionary to assign the colours to each winning party

df['winner_fill']=df['2017_winner'].apply(lambda s: party_colours.get(s,"#aaaaaa"))
#new column that applies the colour for the winning party

election_results = uk_map.merge(df, on='Constituency')
#merge the shape and df together

election_results.plot('winner_fill', figsize=(12,12))
```

[Expected output]
[image]

[My Output]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `apply` in

```
df['winner_fill']=df['2017_winner'].apply(lambda s: party_colours.get(s,"#aaaaaa"))
```

Try `map` instead

```
df['winner_fill'] = df['2017_winner'].map(lambda s: party_colours.get(s,"#aaaaaa"))
```

Comment: I tried but this doesnt resolve the issue. Thanks for trying :D